# Spring Cloud Stream DLQ Native encoding issue: Payload is not byte[]

Tags: spring-integration, avro, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Since we have enabled native decoding on our consumer (Spring Cloud Stream 2.2) to make the integration of our application smother with other tools, the following error has been come up:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Native decoding is used on the consumer. Payload is not byte[] and no serializer is set on the DLQ producer.
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.ensureDlqMessageCanBeProperlySerialized(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.lambda$getErrorMessageHandler$7(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:905)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:461)
```

I have tried to set native encoding for dlq or even set an avro serializer, but it didn't work. I suspect I am not using the right property/address for it:

```
spring:
  cloud.stream:
    kafka:
      bindings:
        input:
          consumer:
            enableDlq: true
            dlqName: dlq # Twitter crawler dead letter queue kafka topic
            dlqProducerProperties:
              useNativeEncoding: true
              value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
              key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a key serializer not a deserializer
2. The properties need to go into the general `configuration` bucket

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-producer-properties.configuration.key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-producer-properties.configuration.value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enable-dlq: true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.use-native-decoding=true
```

Comment: That's right a serializer is required not a deserializer. Something I am confused about is the way that variables are defined. Almost in all the examples and documents camel case has been used for the properties, but occasionally by checking the source code I found some of them are changed to kebab case. Is there an easy way I can find out what property name I should use? For example, printing out all the property names or something like that.

Comment: Well-known (camelCase) properties are in the documentation, the various *Properties classes (e.g. KafkaProducerProperties) and in metadata used by IDEs for content-assist/completion. All other arbitrary Kafka properties must be supplied in the general configuration property buckets.

Comment: Does that accept both types?  For example, I can see dlqProducerProperties and dlq-producer-properties. Is there some sort of strategy class that is set to accept both types of naming?

Comment: Adding the configuration bucket did the trick. Thanks.

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqProducerProperties.configuration.useNativeEncoding: true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqProducerProperties.configuration.value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.dlqProducerProperties.configuration.key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Comment: P.S: I have checked with kebab-case for the mentioned properties and it doesn't make any difference. I guess there should be some sort of conversation happening behind the seen to make these property names the same.

Comment: It's a Spring Boot feature. You can use camelCase fooBar or hyphenated foo-bar for bindings to *Properties classes. Your choice.